# SQL Query Sanatization

Tags: passwords, sql-injection, encoding

It seems to me SQL injection could be avoided by just converting everything to a simple encoding like base64 that doesn't have any harmful symbols.

In the classic query `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${username}'"`, if the user inputs, say, `' OR 1=1;--`, then that would turn into `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' OR 1=1"`, and I'm pretty sure most of you can see the problem with that.

However, if simple base64 encoding was used, that would instead turn into `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'JyBPUiAxPTE7LS0='"`, and could then be decoded when retrieved. This would also allow for symbols and spaces in usernames/passwords.

Unless I am severely misjudging something, this seems a lot simpler than just blacklisting certain words and symbols.

Comment: Are you doing this base64 encoding via javascript or in the web page?  In a programming language such as php or what?

Comment: Theoretical discussion. Not doing it at all.

Comment: The more common approach is to use parameterized SQL. That way you aren't trying to do non-standard encoding/decoding every time you access the data, yet it's not possible to violate the parameters

Comment: And convert everything to `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` preventing date and integer comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This would also allow for symbols and spaces... blacklisting certain
>   words and symbols...

What you are talking about? What blacklisting? From the security point of view passwords can contain **anything** you want. To prevent SQL injection any reasonable application uses **prepared statements**: Java, C#, PHP. In your case it will generate following SQL, which return no result (unless you really have such a strange user name):

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ''' OR 1=1;--'"
```

Blacklisting of some **symbols** is done for better **usability, not for security**. How would user count spaces, how will he distinguish if there are 2 or 3 spaces in a sequence? How would user enter TAB symbol?

Blacklisting of some **passwords** like "123" or "abc" is done to prevent guessing them, to prevent dictionary attacks.